# Ruby on Rails: Ransack undefined method `result`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I'm new to ROR, so this could be a very simple problem.

I have just installed the ransack gem for my web application. I am wanting to search on project names and clients in my database. I have an index page view, which I use for my homepage, then a search page, which uses a search action that I created.

```
def index
@projects = Project.all

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @projects }
  end
 end


def search

  @q = Project.search(params[:q])
  @project_search = @q.result(:distinct => true)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # search.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @projects }
  end
end
```

Here is part of my search view:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :project_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :project_name %>
  <%= f.label :client %>
  <%= f.text_field :client %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I try and load the search page, I get this error:

undefined method `search'

With the extracted source being in my project controller at this line

```
@q = Project.search(params[:q])
```

Hopefully it's an easy fix, and you can explain what I'm doing wrong so I learn.

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've added my index action above to show you that I have an index action, and a search action. Here is my routes.rb file as well.

```
FinalApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :projects
match "search" => "projects#search", :as => :search
root :to => 'projects#index'
end
```

SECOND EDIT:

I hadn't restarted my server. I now have another error.

undefined method `result'

With the extracted source being in my project controller at this line

```
@project_search = @q.result(:distinct => true)
```

THIRD EDIT:

Another error :/

undefined method `schema_cache'

With the extracted source being in my project controller at this line

```
@q = Project.search(params[:q])
```

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: sqlite3. I just left the default database when I ran the scaffold command when I first started making my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Problem solved in another question: [Ruby on Rails: Advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609005/ruby-on-rails-advanced-search/11610450#11610450)**

I have never used the gem `ransack`, but I think your first line `def search` should be `def index` and than you define the `search method` somewhere else... or have you included a route for `search` in your routes.rb?

Anyway, what you are looking for is a very simple search and I don't think you need any gem for it.

You can define the search method in your model:

product.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

products_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:search])
end
```

The search form can be included anywhere in your application:

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Please take a look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form/) and if you need an advanced search look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form/).

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Please see my edit above. I have watched both rail casts videos many times before, and my main problem is that they are outdated. I need to have an advanced search form so I can search over many different fields, to help narrow down search results from a large database. I looked at using meta_search, sunspot, thinking-sphinx, and so far I havn't been able to get any of them to search on more values. I hope you understand what I mean. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, I understand what you mean, but when you start including to many gems you might face incompatibilities. For this reason I prefer to always create my own search, even if it is advanced. For example, you can search in many fields, lets say `name` and `surname`: `find(:all, :conditions => ['name OR surname LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])`. I think you should give a try to create your own methods for searching....

Answer (score 2):

And you are sure you ran Bundle Install after adding the Gem to your Gemfile and restarted instance or have correct development env settings?

Ransack adds the search method so it would seem it is not properly installed.

Comment: I stupidly hadn't restarted the server, Thanks!I now have another problem. One line later :/, please see edit in original post.