# Ruby on Rails: Advanced search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, textbox

I'm having trouble understanding the best way to make a advanced search form. I have had a good search on the internet, looking at some ways, but I can't get them to work, as most of the suggestions are outdated. I have asked a question already, but I think I was too specific and I wasn't able to fix my problem. I am wanting to search on different text boxes and drop down boxes with one search button.

EDIT2:

projects_controller:

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @projects }
    end
  end

def search
@project_search = Project.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 2, :page => params[:page])


end




  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.json
  def new
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create

    @project = Project.new(params[:project])


    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @project.exception_pm = params[:new_exception_pm] unless params[:new_exception_pm].blank?
    @project.project_owner = params[:new_project_owner] unless params[:new_project_owner].blank?
    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
    @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
    @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /projects/1
  # PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end




private

  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def sort_column
    Project.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "project_name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
end
```

Search View:

```
<h1>Search</h1>

<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
  <%= text_field_tag :project_name, params[:project_name] %>
  <%= text_field_tag :client, params[:client] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>



<table class = "pretty">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "project_name", "Project name" %> </th>
    <th><%= sortable "client", "Client" %></th>
    <th>Exception pm</th>
    <th>Project owner</th>
    <th>Tech</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Industry</th>
    <th>Financials</th>
    <th>Business div</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>End date</th>
<% if false %>
    <th>Entry date</th>
    <th>Edited date</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Lessons learned</tStackh>
    <th>Customer benifits</th>
    <th>Keywords</th>
    <!th></th>
    <!th></th>
    <!th></th>
<% end %>
  </tr>

<% @project_search.each do |t| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= t.project_name %></td>
    <td><%= t.client %></td>
    <td><%= t.exception_pm %></td>
    <td><%= t.project_owner %></td>
    <td><%= t.tech %></td>
    <td><%= t.role %></td>
    <td><%= t.industry %></td>
    <td><%= t.financials %></td>
    <td><%= t.business_div %></td>
    <td><%= t.status %></td>
    <td><%= t.start_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.end_date %></td>
<% if false %>
    <td><%= t.entry_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.edited_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.summary %></td>
    <td><%= t.lessons_learned %></td>
    <td><%= t.customer_benifits %></td>
    <td><%= t.keywords %></td>
<% end %>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
<%= will_paginate (@project_search) %>


<%= button_to "Search Again?", search_path, :method => "get" %>

<%# end %>
<%= button_to "Home", projects_path, :method => "get" %>
```

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech

validates_presence_of :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :end_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech



def self.search search_term
 return scoped unless search_term.present?
 where find(:all, :conditions => ['project_name OR client LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%"])
end

end
```

Routes:

```
FinalApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :projects
match "search" => "projects#search", :as => :search
root :to => 'projects#index'
end
```

As you can see, I'm still a fair bit away from having a finished application. I am trying to make a search form that will be able to search on the following fields: Project name, Client, ID, Industry, Role, Technology, Project Owner, Status, Start Date, End Date, and Keywords. The search form would have either text boxes or drop down menus depending on which field the user was searching for. I am wanting to chain each field and search on them all in one go. Before, I was only using project_name, and client as examples to make it easier for you to understand my code. Hopefully you can see now what I am trying to do.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised)? This might help you along.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a new controller called `search`.

Your search form:

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :project, params[:project] %>
  <%= text_field_tag :client, params[:client] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

incude in your routes.rb:

```
get "search/index"
```

your search controller:

```
def index
  #store all the projects that match the name searched
  @projects = Project.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:project]}%")  
  #store all the clients that match the name searched    
  @clients = Client.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client]}%")
end
```

Now you can play with `@projects` and `@clients` in the index view.

Just be careful, because these variables might became nil if there is no match for the search.

**EDIT - I am assuming you have two models `Project` and `Client`** - if you cannot create a new controller you can create the search action in your current controller.

```
def search
  #store all the projects that match the name searched
  @projects = Project.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:project]}%")  
  #store all the clients that match the name searched    
  @clients = Client.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client]}%")
end
```

And than you can use the `@projects` and `@clients` in the search view.

If you are trying to display the results in somewhere else (for example `index` view), you can just move the above to the correct action.

```
 def index
  ....
  #store all the projects that match the name searched
  @projects = Project.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:project]}%")  
  #store all the clients that match the name searched    
  @clients = Client.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client]}%")
end
```

**EDIT 2** - OK, you are trying to search by a combination of fields in the same model:

You and change your search method to add these two fields:

```
def self.search(search_project, search_client) 
  return scoped unless search_project.present? || search_client.present?
  where(['project_name LIKE ? AND client LIKE ?', "%#{search_project}%", "%#{search_client}%"])
end
```

But please note the `||` will return scope if your search_project OR search_client are not present, you can change for AND (&&) if you prefer.

Also, the `AND` will return only if both match, I mean the combination of search... You can also change it to `OR` if you want.

Having the search form:

Your search form:

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :project, params[:project] %>
  <%= text_field_tag :client, params[:client] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Then your controller must send the combination to the model:

```
@project_search = Project.search(params[:project], params[:client]).all
```

I think it will solve the problem...

Comment: Hi again Gabriel, I changed my search form to the suggestion you gave me, however I kept the path the same, as I am struggling to create a new search controller. The way I had my application set out before worked when there was only one text box. Surely it can't be that difficult to add another on, and chain the search together?

Comment: I was looking your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577937/ruby-on-rails-search-form-multiple-search-fields) and I didn't understand if you have one or two models. The suggested answer is trying to search client name inside Project model and it will not work if you have two models.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not making myself clear. I only have one model, Project.rb. I will upload my controller, search view, routes, model files so you get a better picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have added more of my code. If you need anymore to understand what I'm trying to do, just ask. Thanks Gabriel

Comment: is there any way to enhance the view part with some sort of validation? I mean suppose if there was a "price" with "min" and "max" fields. (they should be numbers, also min < max)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [MetaSearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) in my application and found it quite convenient. If you've already considered it, what problems did you have?

There's also [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) by the same author, it's a successor to MetaSearch.

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation can be found in this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised)

Basically, we have to test if the params contain a specific field and create the filter. See the example below:

```
def find_products
  products = Product.order(:name)
  products = products.where("name like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
  products = products.where(category_id: category_id) if category_id.present?
  products = products.where("price >= ?", min_price) if min_price.present?
  products = products.where("price <= ?", max_price) if max_price.present?
  products
end
```

An alternative is [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). Ransack enables the creation of both simple and advanced search forms for your Ruby on Rails application