# How could I use a javascript variable inside of a ruby if statement?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm trying to implement [advanced search](http://www.collegeanswerz.com/advanced-search)(<= only partially functional) for my website, but I'm having some trouble mixing the javascript code with the ruby code.

I want the table to be updated accordingly after the user clicks a button to specify the type of school he's looking for.  Ex. if the user clicks 'Huge' for size, it'll only show schools with over 25,000 kids (see the link).

This is the code I've got so far:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sort_button").click(function(){
            $("#tbody1").html('');
            <% @national_university_enrollment.each do |school| %>              
                if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'size_all' ) {
                    $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'intimate' ) {
                    <% if school.enrollment < 3000 %>
                      $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                    <% end %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'small' ) {
                    <% if school.enrollment >= 3000  && school.enrollment < 7000 %>
                        $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                    <% end %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'medium' ) {
                    <% if school.enrollment >= 7000  && school.enrollment < 15000 %>
                        $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                    <% end %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'large' ) {
                    <% if school.enrollment >= 15000  && school.enrollment < 25000 %>
                        $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                    <% end %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'huge' ) {
                    <% if school.enrollment >= 25000 %>
                        $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                    <% end %>
                }
            <% end %>
        });
    });
<% end %>
```

I have at least 8 more criteria I want to sort by, each with at least 5 categories.  So simply nesting if statements the way I have the code now will not work.

I want to have upper and lower variables for each criteria specifying how the ruby if statement will act.  For example, I'd have javascript variables `min_size` and `max_size`, and then the ruby if statement would say `<% if school.enrollment >= min_size && school.enrollment < max_size %>`.  However, that doesn't seem to be working because its not letting me use the javascript variable in the ruby if statement.

Question: Is it possible to use javascript variables inside of ruby if statements?

Also, if there's an easier way of going about this... I'm all ears!  For example, the reason I'm using javascript is to see what button is clicked, so if I could do that in ruby, that would solve the problem I'm having.

EDIT: Could I declare a ruby variable inside of a javascript if statement, and then use the ruby variable later in a ruby if statement?

I'm trying to do something like this now but it doesn't seem to be working.  What I'm trying to do is have a javascript if statement, and declare a ruby variable inside it.  The reason I'm thinking that it's possible is because in the first batch of code I posted in this question, I have ruby if statements that got executed inside of javascript if statements.  So I figure that if a ruby if statement could work inside a javascript if statement, a ruby variable could be declared inside of a javascript if statement.

```
<tbody id="tbody1">
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sort_button").click(function(){
            alert('clicked');
            $("#tbody1").html('');
            <% @national_university_enrollment.each do |school| %>              
                if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'size_all' ) {
                    <% min_size = 0 %>
                    <% max_size = 1000000 %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'intimate' ) {
                    <% min_size = 0 %>
                    <% max_size = 2999 %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'small' ) {
                    <% min_size = 3000 %>
                    <% max_size = 6999 %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'medium' ) {
                    <% min_size = 7000 %>
                    <% max_size = 14999 %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'large' ) {
                    <% min_size = 15000 %>
                    <% max_size = 24999 %>
                }
                else if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'huge' ) {
                    <% min_size = 25000 %>
                    <% max_size = 1000000 %>
                }

                <% if school.enrollment >= min_size && school.enrollment < max_size %>
                    $('<tr><td class="name_column"><%= link_to "#{school.name}", "#{school.url}" %></td><td class="rank_column"><%= "#{school.us_news_ranking}" %></td><td class="location_column"><%= "#{school.location}" %></td><td class="setting_column"><%= "#{school.setting}" %></td><td class="size_column"><%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.enrollment}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="cost_column">$<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.in_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %>/ $<%= number_with_delimiter("#{school.out_of_state_tuition + school.room_and_board}", :delimiter => ',') %></td><td class="math_column"><%= "#{school.sat_math_25} - #{school.sat_math_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.sat_reading_25} - #{school.sat_reading_75}" %></td><td><%= "#{school.act_composite_25} - #{school.act_composite_75}" %></td></tr>').appendTo("#tbody1");
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        });
    });
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Think about this: Where is the javascript code executed, and where is the ruby code executed.

Comment: Of course not, Ruby is executed on the server, JavaScript on the client (for the purposes of this discussion). Unrelated, but I find this essentially illegible.

Comment: Ok :/.  So how could I go about implementing the search functionality?  I know I could have a search form, but I want to use javascript because it's much faster.

Comment: Use ajax? Or refresh the page with only the data you need? It's unclear from the code what's happening.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11610450/36866

Comment: @some, that looks like it doesn't use javascript.  Is there a way for me to do this with javascript?  If not, I could imitate that question, but I'd like to do it with javascript if I can because it's much faster that way.  (sorry if my terminology isn't correct; I'm a beginner)

Comment: They don't get executed in JavaScript statements. They get executed on the server which renders JavaScript, which is sent to the client, which executes JavaScript. This will all be very difficult until you understand that the server side executes ruby, renders HTML and JavaScript, sends it to the client, which displays and executes the results of the rendering.

Comment: @DaveNewton - so does that mean that I can't implement this search functionality in the "fast executing javascript way"?

Comment: I have no idea what you think you mean by that. If you just want to hide/show divs based on clicks, render it all at once and set up click handlers. If you need to fetch more data use ajax.

Comment: I want to hide/show content based on clicks.  I could hide/show divs, but I'd need like 10s of thousands of divs to account for all the different permutations of which criteria the user has selected.

Comment: @AdamZerner I'm sorry, but there are too many things wrong with your code and your approach to this problem than I can answer in a comment of 600 characters.

Comment: @some could you point me in the right direction? What would be the best way to implement this (taking speed/UX into account)?

Comment: @AdamZerner First you must understand what part of your code is running on the sever side and what parts are running in the client. I don't use ruby on rails myself so I can't help you there.

Comment: About speed... Look at this code: `$(this).attr('id')` First you call function `$` with `this` as argument, then you call another function `attr` with `'id'` as argument. It's nothing wrong with that except you do it multiple times in the same function and get the same value every time. Every function-call is expensive and you do two of them many times without realizing what you are doing. The right approach is to get the value once and store that into a local variable and then use that variable. Instead of if-else-if you should probably use `switch` instead.

Comment: @some thanks for the pointers.  It looks like the most efficient way for me to implement this is in fact to go back and sure up my understanding of the foundations, so I'll do that.

Comment: You gotta pass the data to Rails using Ajax or a similar technology. JS is client-side & Rails is server-side; you have to send the variable through some sort of connecting function, either ajax or reloading the page with params attached