# Ruby on Rails : Advance search, undefined method [ ] for nil:Nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, advanced-search

I am very new to rails and try to make an advance search form which takes two values 'blood_group' and 'area' and based upon that search the records from the database are fetched and will display on the same page (find.html.erb)
     I have tried something in find.html.erb but there is an error occurred 'undefined method [] for nil:Nil class' where my search form exists. please help to get out of this error.

Here is my search form in find.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag find_path , method: :get do %>

             <p> <%= label_tag :blood_group %><br />
              <%= select_tag (:blood_group), options_for_select(%w[ A+ B+ O+ AB+ A- B- O- AB-]), params[:blood_group] %> </p>

             <p> <%= label_tag :area %><br />
              <%= select_tag (:area), options_for_select(%w[Indore Vijay_Nagar Bhawar_Kuwa Rajendra_Nagar Geeta_Bhawan Aerodram Tejaji_Nagar Raj_Mohalla Rajwada Chandan_Nagar Gandhi_Nagar Arvindo MY Bombay_Hospital]) , params[:area] %> </p> 


              <%= submit_tag "Search" , class: "btn btn-primary" , name: nil %>
            <% end %>
```

The error is at the lines where I used select tag.
below is my find action in Donor controller

```
def find

    @donors = Donor.search(params[:blood_group], params[:area]).all 

 end
```

And Donor.rb is as follows

```
class Donor < ActiveRecord::Base


def self.search(blood_group, area)

    return all unless blood_group.present? || area.present?

    where(['blood_group LIKE ? AND area LIKE ?', "%#{blood_group}%", "%#{area}%"])
end
```

end

Comment: <%= select_tag (:blood_group), options_for_select(%w[ A+ B+ O+ AB+ A- B- O- AB-]), params[:blood_group] %> </p> - why are you using params[:blood_group]?

Comment: i guess params[:blood_group] is evaluating to nil in your case.

Comment: @AdnanDevops Just guessing, but incase the form errors, the value will be populated.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Error is at line where i used select_tag in search form

Comment: @AdnanDevops : Yeah the error occurred after putting params[:blood_group] , but what should I do to perform advance search in this case?

Comment: as per the select_tag syntax, the third parameter is used for passing options. See this -http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: @AdnanDevops : Actually I am following this solved question based on advance search where params are used with the form field in search form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609005/ruby-on-rails-advanced-search

Comment: you can remove it and try it out, as when you submit the form you will get the values inside params for blood group and area.

Comment: @AdnanDevops : Thanks it works but it is working only once and if I want to search again I have to refresh the page and than again search

Comment: what issue are you facing when you are trying to search again?

Comment: you can either submit the form as ajax in order to avoid refreshing the page.

Comment: good to hear...I will this add this as the answer now, please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search form must be like this:

```
<%= form_tag find_path , method: :get, remote: true do %>

         <p> <%= label_tag :blood_group %><br />
          <%= select_tag (:blood_group), options_for_select(%w[ A+ B+ O+ AB+ A- B- O- AB-]) %> </p>

         <p> <%= label_tag :area %><br />
          <%= select_tag (:area), options_for_select(%w[Indore Vijay_Nagar Bhawar_Kuwa Rajendra_Nagar Geeta_Bhawan Aerodram Tejaji_Nagar Raj_Mohalla Rajwada Chandan_Nagar Gandhi_Nagar Arvindo MY Bombay_Hospital]) %> </p> 


          <%= submit_tag "Search" , class: "btn btn-primary" , name: nil %>
        <% end %>
```

Modify your controller as:

```
def find
  @donors = Donor.search(params[:blood_group], params[:area]).all 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then add find.js.erb to show the searched content.