# Advanced Search with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I'm creating an advanced search feature on my rails application. I want to add a functionality where I can search and filter based on the user's name and gender. I did this by adding a new model called the search model with two columns: username & gender. I took the inspiration from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUtUquKc2qQ&t=301s), and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609005/ruby-on-rails-advanced-search), but customised the feature greatly to fit my needs for the application. Until now, everything flows successfully, by this I mean that as an admin of the page I can successfully navigate between the two index's of the different models: the users model and the search model. The only problem is that I'm struggling to capture my params (what is being searched) and save it in the controller so it can be viewed in the index of the search model. This is my code for the index of the search model:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<%= form_tag searches_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %>
  <%= select_tag :gender, options_for_select(@users.collect{ |u| [u.gender] }) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

And this is the search_controller:

```
  def index
    @search = Search.all
  end

  def new
    @search = Search.new(params[:username])
    @search = Search.new(params[:gender])
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:users, :gender)
  end
```

This is the index of my search model:

```
<h1> Your Search Results </h1>

<% if @search.nil? %>
  <p> No Results Found </p>

<% else %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= raise %>
  <%= @search %>
</ul>

<% end %>

<p><%= link_to 'All Users',  users_path %></p>
```

`@search` is empty when I raise it in the console. But as you can see below, the params are successfully being saved in the URL of the index page:

```
http://localhost:3000/searches?utf8=%E2%9C%93&username=stella&gender=Female
```

Here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qNmMlThwr7LSgDsgtYfJzsTs-gWD9PlU/view) explaining what I want to do exactly:

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not clear! what do you want? do you want to save the search params while a user search?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qNmMlThwr7LSgDsgtYfJzsTs-gWD9PlU/view?usp=sharing hey @fool-dev thanks for helping out! I attached a video where I explain exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to try to search users based on search params like if `gender=Female` the return all users which is `Females`, right? Then follow the instruction.

In the `search_controller` you return all users based on params

```
def index
    if params[:username] || params[:gender].present?
        @users = User.where('true').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
        @users = @users.where(username: params[:username]) unless params[:username].blank?
        @users = @users.where(gender: params[:gender]) unless params[:gender].blank?
    else
        @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
end
```

then the `searches/index.html.erb` like this, same as your `users`

```
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.username %>
    ..........
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The above part was for only `User` search. Now if you need to save these search params then you use like this

```
Search.create(username: params[:username],gender: params[:gender])
```

it will save these params on every search. Then the index action will look like this

```
def index
    if params[:username] || params[:gender].present?
        @users = User.where('true').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
        @users = @users.where(username: params[:username]) unless params[:username].blank?
        @users = @users.where(gender: params[:gender]) unless params[:gender].blank?

        Search.create(username: params[:username],gender: params[:gender])
    else
        @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
end
```

I hope it's what do you want.

**Update**

First of all, you have missed something like you have used

```
@search = User.where('true').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
@search = User.where(username: params[:username]) unless params[:username].blank?
@search = User.where(gender: params[:gender]) unless params[:gender].blank?
```

in the above code, it will work for only one line not combining three lines because you have separated the model `User`

instead of

```
@search = User.where('true').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
@search = @search.where(username: params[:username]) unless params[:username].blank?
@search = @search.where(gender: params[:gender]) unless params[:gender].blank?
```

that is the combined like while putting `username` it will work while put `gender` also it will work, but your code always executes the last line.

The new query is for search (You can use if you need)

```
@search = User.where(username: params[:username]).where(gender: params[:gender]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

This query equivalent to

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'xyz' AND "users"."gender" = 'xyz'"
```

it will make condition and like `username` and `gender` should be must match, otherwise false

**Point 2** While you use the `like` operator and the `%male%` the percent sign  it will search any values that have `male` in any position, when in the lis **Female** and you **male** it will match because **Female** caring with **male** that's why search result return **Female** while you search for **male**, you need exact search like below.

Please advise if misunderstanding you or me.

```
@search = User.where(username: params[:username]).where(gender: params[:gender]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

Comment: Hello @fool-dev! Once again thank you helping out. I used some of your solution but changed it a bit because it wasn't fully working. Now I have another problem. I explain it in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Y6nDDIxzUfDU1yChL0jys1gxsbE35aH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey @AlyDabbous, It's a little bit difficult to find out what's actually going, see the **Update** section in the answer. I have seen the video and I'm confused about `create` method.